# Linq or XSLT combine multiple variable elements into one

Tags: xml, linq, xslt

I have been struggling with this transform and perhaps, someone here can shed a bit of light on the issues other than me not having much xslt practice. With the xml below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <recipes version="1.0">
    <name language="en">195P 290000
        000015 000010</name>
     <recipe size="small">
    <subsequence name="START">
      <TMP> 90</TMP>
      <DV> 0</DV>
      <LG> 00FF0000</LG>
      <CB> 0000FF00</CB>
      <TS> 000000FF</TS>
      <BS> 00320A00</BS>
    </subsequence>
   <subsequence name="FR">
      <FWV>453</FWV>
      <RWV>232</RWV>
      <AP>21</AP>
    </subsequence> 
  </recipe>
  <recipe size="medium">
    <subsequence name="START">
      <TMP>215</TMP>
      <DV> 0</DV>
      <LG> 00060000</LG>
      <CB> 00969696</CB>
      <TS> 00191919</TS>
      <BS> 00060606</BS>
    </subsequence>
    <subsequence name="FR">
      <FWV>357</FWV>
      <RWV>0</RWV>
      <AP>0</AP>
    </subsequence>   
     <subsequence name="VC">
      <PS>29</PS>
      <TM>5</TM>
      <AP>0</AP>
    </subsequence>
    <subsequence name="FR">
      <FWV> 0</FWV>
      <RWV>45</RWV>
      <AP>15</AP>
    </subsequence>
       <subsequence name="PG">
      <PS>20</PS>
      <TM>27</TM>
      <LG>00060000</LG>
      <CB>00040404</CB>
      <TS>00040404</TS>
      <BS>00202020</BS>
    </subsequence>
    <subsequence name="BO">
      <BT>4</BT>
    </subsequence>
 </recipe>
   <recipe size="large">
   <subsequence name="FR">
      <FWV>33357</FWV>
      <RWV>0</RWV>
      <AP>0</AP>
    </subsequence>   
     <subsequence name="VC">
      <PS>29</PS>
      <TM>5</TM>
      <AP>0</AP>
    </subsequence>
    <subsequence name="FR">
      <FWV> 2222</FWV>
      <RWV>333</RWV>
      <AP>15</AP>
    </subsequence>
       <subsequence name="PG">
      <PS>20</PS>
      <TM>27</TM>
      <LG>00060000</LG>
      <CB>00040404</CB>
      <TS>00040404</TS>
      <BS>00202020</BS>
    </subsequence>
    <subsequence name="BO">
      <BT>4</BT>
    </subsequence>
 </recipe>
</recipes>
```

you can say each size has a start sequence but beyond that it is a variable subsequence with FR, VC, PR, BT attributes happening in any order . What I cant figure much less wrap my head around is how to get the transform into something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <recipes version="1.0">
    <name language="en">195P 290000 000015 000010</name>
    <subsequence name="START">
      <small>
        <TMP> 90</TMP>
        <DV> 0</DV>
        <LG> 00FF0000</LG>
        <CB> 0000FF00</CB>
        <TS> 000000FF</TS>
        <BS> 00320A00</BS>
      </small>
      <medium>
        <TMP>215</TMP>
        <DV> 0</DV>
        <LG> 00060000</LG>
        <CB> 00969696</CB>
        <TS> 00191919</TS>
        <BS> 00060606</BS>
      </medium>
      <large>
        ..values
      </large>
    </subsequence>
    <subsequence name="FR">
      <small>
       ...values
      </small>
      <medium>
          ..values
      </medium>
    <large>
         ..values
    </large>
    </subsequence>
    <subsequence name="VC">
      <small>
       ...values (again if any
      </small>
      <medium>
          ..values
      </medium>
     <large>
         ..values
    </large>
    </subsequence>
      <subsequence name="FR">
      <small>
       ...values
      </small>
      <medium>
          ..values
      </medium>
    <large>
         ..values
    </large>
    </subsequence>
     ..and so on
    </recipes>
```

Of course the start is easy, but after that I lose my head. I need to combine the next sibling values if it exists and is the same as the others in document order. More so if 
large order is FR VC PG  and Medium order is FR VC PG I would combine those together if they where not the same I would induce zeros for values. IE if the first large was FR and the first Medium was VC I would just take one in any order as one would have zeroes anyway.

I have given up trying to use XSLT for this problem, but wondered if it was even possible as it will by far clean up the code and allow for a single object model to be serialized/deserialized.

Comment: What version of XSLT? It's absolutely possible with XSLT, but approaches will vary depending on what version of XSLT you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what I came up with and I am aware it isn't perfect... If anyone has a better alternative I would love to see it.

```
//function for applying annotations similar to MSDN example (shame on me)
static XElement XForm(XElement source)
{

    if (source.Annotation<XAttribute>() != null)
    {
        XAttribute anno = source.Annotation<XAttribute>();
        return new XElement( source.Name, anno, source.Attributes(), source.Nodes());
    }
    else
    {
        return new XElement(source.Name,
            source.Attributes(),
            source.Nodes().Select(n =>
                {
                    XElement el = n as XElement;
                    if (el == null)
                        return n;
                    else
                        return XForm(el);
                }
                )
        );
    }
}

XElement root = XElement.Load(".xml");
root.DescendantNodes().OfType<XComment>().Remove();

int subIncrement = 0;

foreach (var el in root.Descendants("subsequence"))
{
    if (el.Attribute("name").Value == "START") { subIncrement = 0; }
    el.AddAnnotation(new XAttribute("key", el.FirstAttribute.Value + subIncrement));
    subIncrement += 1;
}

XElement newRoot = XForm(root);

var transform = new XElement("recipe", from data in
                                    (from seq in newRoot.Descendants("subsequence")
                                     select new XElement(seq.Attribute("key").Value
                                                        ,new XElement(seq.Ancestors().First().FirstAttribute.Value
                                                                     ,seq.Nodes()
                                                                     )
                                                        )
                                    )
                               group data by data.Name.ToString() into groups
                              select new XElement((string)groups.Key , groups.Nodes()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually that's relatively easy in XSLT.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:key name="kSubsequenceByName" match="subsequence" use="@name" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="recipe">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="subsequence">
    <xsl:variable name="myGroup" select="key('kSubsequenceByName', @name)" />
    <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id($myGroup)">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$myGroup" mode="translate" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="subsequence" mode="translate">
    <xsl:element name="{../@size}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

gives you, with your input sample:

```
<recipes version="1.0">
  <name language="en">195P 290000
        000015 000010</name>
  <subsequence name="START">
    <small>
      <TMP>90</TMP>
      <DV>0</DV>
      <LG>00FF0000</LG>
      <CB>0000FF00</CB>
      <TS>000000FF</TS>
      <BS>00320A00</BS>
    </small>
    <medium>
      <TMP>215</TMP>
      <DV>0</DV>
      <LG>00060000</LG>
      <CB>00969696</CB>
      <TS>00191919</TS>
      <BS>00060606</BS>
    </medium>
  </subsequence>
  <subsequence name="FR">
    <medium>
      <FWV>357</FWV>
      <RWV>0</RWV>
      <AP>0</AP>
    </medium>
    <medium>
      <FWV>0</FWV>
      <RWV>45</RWV>
      <AP>15</AP>
    </medium>
  </subsequence>
  <subsequence name="VC">
    <medium>
      <PS>29</PS>
      <TM>5</TM>
      <AP>0</AP>
    </medium>
  </subsequence>
  <subsequence name="PG">
    <medium>
      <PS>20</PS>
      <TM>27</TM>
      <LG>00060000</LG>
      <CB>00040404</CB>
      <TS>00040404</TS>
      <BS>00202020</BS>
    </medium>
  </subsequence>
  <subsequence name="BO">
    <medium>
      <BT>4</BT>
    </medium>
  </subsequence>
  .
  .
  .
  .
</recipes>
```

Concepts to know (or to read up on):

- the identity template
- `<xsl:key>` and Muenchian grouping
- template modes

Comment: This does good, and I apologies for not being extremely clear, but multiple tags shouldn't group IE FR medium medium it should read left to right in per size order (visualized as columns) so the first FR should be medium 357 0 0 large 412 0 0. Is this change trivial?

Comment: There's no need to accept my answer, it does not yet solve your problem, after all. (It's past midnight over here right now, I'll look into this tomorrow. Un-accept my answer for now, so others will get a chance to answer earlier.)

Comment: Alright, I didn't mind working/learning through; it was an early thanks.

Comment: @KungFu - In your first comment you say the first FR large should be 412 0 0. How do you get that given your input sample? You don't have anything in the "large" recipe in your example. I will add a 2.0 answer too.

Comment: @DanielHaley my mistake this should be the first in the same sequence order as an example for the large IE start fr

Answer (score 0):

Here's an XSLT 2.0 option using `xsl:for-each-group` instead of muenchian grouping.

**XML Input** (modified to be well-formed)

```
<recipes version="1.0">
    <name language="en">195P 290000
        000015 000010</name>
    <recipe size="small">
        <subsequence name="START">
            <TMP> 90</TMP>
            <DV> 0</DV>
            <LG> 00FF0000</LG>
            <CB> 0000FF00</CB>
            <TS> 000000FF</TS>
            <BS> 00320A00</BS>
        </subsequence>
    </recipe>
    <recipe size="medium">
        <subsequence name="START">
            <TMP>215</TMP>
            <DV> 0</DV>
            <LG> 00060000</LG>
            <CB> 00969696</CB>
            <TS> 00191919</TS>
            <BS> 00060606</BS>
        </subsequence>
        <subsequence name="FR">
            <FWV>357</FWV>
            <RWV>0</RWV>
            <AP>0</AP>
        </subsequence>   
        <subsequence name="VC">
            <PS>29</PS>
            <TM>5</TM>
            <AP>0</AP>
        </subsequence>
        <subsequence name="FR">
            <FWV> 0</FWV>
            <RWV>45</RWV>
            <AP>15</AP>
        </subsequence>
        <subsequence name="PG">
            <PS>20</PS>
            <TM>27</TM>
            <LG>00060000</LG>
            <CB>00040404</CB>
            <TS>00040404</TS>
            <BS>00202020</BS>
        </subsequence>
        <subsequence name="BO">
            <BT>4</BT>
        </subsequence>
    </recipe>
    <recipe size="large">
        .
        .
        .
        .
    </recipe>
</recipes>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node() except recipe"/>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="recipe/subsequence" group-by="@name">
                <xsl:variable name="name" select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="/*/recipe[subsequence/@name=$name]" group-by="@size">
                        <xsl:element name="{current-grouping-key()}">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="subsequence[@name=$name and not(preceding-sibling::subsequence/@name=$name)]/*"/>
                        </xsl:element>                        
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>        
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<recipes version="1.0">
   <name language="en">195P 290000
        000015 000010</name>
   <subsequence name="START">
      <small>
         <TMP> 90</TMP>
         <DV> 0</DV>
         <LG> 00FF0000</LG>
         <CB> 0000FF00</CB>
         <TS> 000000FF</TS>
         <BS> 00320A00</BS>
      </small>
      <medium>
         <TMP>215</TMP>
         <DV> 0</DV>
         <LG> 00060000</LG>
         <CB> 00969696</CB>
         <TS> 00191919</TS>
         <BS> 00060606</BS>
      </medium>
   </subsequence>
   <subsequence name="FR">
      <medium>
         <FWV>357</FWV>
         <RWV>0</RWV>
         <AP>0</AP>
      </medium>
   </subsequence>
   <subsequence name="VC">
      <medium>
         <PS>29</PS>
         <TM>5</TM>
         <AP>0</AP>
      </medium>
   </subsequence>
   <subsequence name="PG">
      <medium>
         <PS>20</PS>
         <TM>27</TM>
         <LG>00060000</LG>
         <CB>00040404</CB>
         <TS>00040404</TS>
         <BS>00202020</BS>
      </medium>
   </subsequence>
   <subsequence name="BO">
      <medium>
         <BT>4</BT>
      </medium>
   </subsequence>
</recipes>
```

Comment: I updated the original question for clarity in what I am after, sorry for any confusion. Your output has one FR when the sequence would have FR VC FR PG BO